# Pain in forearm while doing bicep curls

Tags: pain, curls, forearm

When i'm doing curl or bicep exercise (more when my palm face the ceiling) I feel pain in my forearm between my wrist and my elbow. The pain is situated on the side of the ulna.

The pain seems to come when I release my grip.

Did someone know from where it's coming; muscles, nerves, ... ?

EDIT : I've check with a professional and it seems to be my muscle the "Extensor carpi ulnaris"

Did someone know if it come from a bad form or too much weight ?

Thanks

Comment: Your Biceps and brachioradialis insert on your radius. My assumption is that your forearm extensors or flexors (back and front of your forearm respectively) have something going on. Sometimes they can develop fascial adhesions (fascia sticks to muscle causing irriation) which just take an athletic trainer, massage therapist, etc. to fix. If the pain persists, becomes worse, or you are just generally concerned you should go to your primary care physician ASAP.

Comment: Medical advice is off topic, and this question is very individual in nature.

Comment: Thanks Grohlier, and JohnP I don't want medical advice, just want to know if it's muscle pain. It's not because it's not common that I can't ask.

Comment: but Grohlier, i've seen the image og the muscle that insert in the radius but it'S really on the other side of the forearm, I was also wondering if I was doing my curls the wrong way.

Comment: @JohnP: I'm not certain this qualified as a medical question. He's not asking for a diagnosis or a treatment. If someone asked about tightness in their legs after running, would we hesitate to talk about foam rolling the IT band?

Comment: @Greg - We don't know. It could be muscle, tendon, ligament, nerve or any combination. Pain (as opposed to an ache) is a signal that something is wrong. Get it checked out.

Comment: @DocFaustus - It is a bit of a gray area, but the basic question is "Tell me why this hurts".

Comment: @JohnP Or the question could be "tell me if i'm doing something wrong while training, because me arm hurts ?" ;) I hate it when a question get closed ... :(

Comment: I've just read the FAQ Again and i don't understand why this was closed ? it say to not ask question about medical problem or injury not related to exercise, but my question was related to exercise... could somebody tell me exactly whats wrong in my question

Comment: The reason this question was closed (in my opinion) is that even though you might have intended it to be a question about form... Because there is a pain involved, no one can tell you if it is a form issue, muscle strain/sprain/tear, bone problem, etc. Also, the other bone in your forearm is your Ulna, just FYI. :) You should consult a professional about the pain though. Good luck.

Comment: @Grohlier thanks !  but it's not alarming , seriously I only get the pain when I'm doing curls I can live with it, it's just anoying...

Comment: @Greg no problem. Just remember that even if it is mild and you "can live with it" that pain is your body's way of saying something is wrong and needs to be fixed.

Comment: "Did someone know if it come from a bad form or too much weight?" Can you not ask the professional that diagnosed you? Alternatively, it would be better if you just uploaded a form video and we could check your form. That would be much more on-topic for this site.

Comment: Hey there, I have actually suffered from the same, exact symptom a few years ago, and it happened only when I released the weight after doing preacher-curls. I did a lot of asking around and I was told that this is often due to weak forearm tendons. I took a year off from preacher curls (instead I did sitting dumbell curls and forearm exercises) and it felt much better. I came back to preacher curls recently and I feel almost no pain now. Good luck.

Comment: @Greg The question still has not changed with your edits. The answers you would get would be no different than your [first revision](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/revisions/11710/1). My suggestion for making this more on-topic for this site would be to ask how to prevent pain in the forearm while training your bicep, focusing on the aspects of weight and proper form that might contribute to that pain. This avoids everyone from entering unending speculation of what you could have possibly done without knowing more about your own personal history and potentially offering *bad* advice.

Comment: If you have more questions about this site, how your question fits, and the scope and [faq] of the site, you and everyone else here should bring this discussion to the [meta]. I'm locking this question until this question's content can be resolved on the Meta rather than there.